# AngularJS directive with replacing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've developed AngularJS directives to add rectangle into SVG document:

```
  <svg version="1.1" width="200" height="100">

<g>
  <!-- Works -->
  <g dir-rect1="" viz-settings="settings.rect1" />
  <!-- Doesn't work -->
  <g dir-rect2="" viz-settings="settings.rect2" />
</g>
```

The only difference is between the directives is that the dir-rect1 directive doesn't use replace and the dir-rect2 directive use:

```
app.directive('dirRect2', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      vizSettings: '=',
    },
    replace:true, // <--- DOESN'T WORK
    template: '<rect fill="{{vizSettings.fill}}" stroke="{{vizSettings.fill}}" width="{{vizSettings.width}}" height="{{vizSettings.height}}" />',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      console.debug($scope);
    }
  };
});
```

Why when I use replacing in my dirRect2 directive, I cannot see a rect?
It seems that generated code is right in both cases.
You can see example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jyxqBISAZUJcyBdCwPDQ?p=preview).

Comment: Be careful with replace in angular is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. replace is deprecated so, I don't recommend you to use it
2. replace copy the attributes to the children, and that is your problem.

The second directive generates this:

```
<rect fill="#111111" stroke="#111111" width="10" height="20" dir-rect2="" viz-settings="settings.rect2" class="ng-isolate-scope"></rect>
```

And it seems that dir-rect2 and viz-settings is breaking the svg in some way... if you remove this attributes with the same code... svg seems to work:

```
<rect fill="#111111" stroke="#111111" width="10" height="20" ></rect>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `dirRect1` **replace** is **`false`** (default value) and in `dirRect2` is **`true`**, so you see a different behavior between the two directives.

The rectangle is not displayed since "`rect`" tag is required to render the shape in svg! (as I just realized since I never played with svg)

(when you define "`replace: true`" you are telling Angular to remove the original tag on which the directive is applied)